# how can i reuse progressbar that is created by jquery in a div

Tags: jquery

I want to use the same progressbar multiple times that is crated by jquery in a div.
So how can i reinitiate the progressbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's stopping you from just doing `$('#yourelement').progressbar('value', 0);` to reset the progress bar back to 0%?

Unless you're not using jQuery UI, in which cause you'd just have to do `$('#yourelement').width('0%')` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourprogressbarid').progressbar('option', 'value', 0);
```

Assuming you are using jQuery UI progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this would help:

I had a problem when re-using a JQuery ProgressBar, because when you reset the progress bar to 0, it takes some time for the bar to move back to 0 (since ProgressBar smoothly moves from one value to the next).

My answer was to reset the progressBar to 0, when it is hidden.

So the algorithm is:

1. process starting (e.g. file upload)
2. show progress bar
3. update progress as the process completes

   $('#jqProgressID').progressBar(percent);
4. when process completes, hide the progress bar
5. NOW reset the progress bar to 0:

   $('#jqProgressID').progressBar(0);

This allows you to re-use the progress bar, without the user having to view the bar resetting to 0.